# Как удалить лишнее из строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, парсер, list

Есть строки, например:

```
12 PARFUMEURS  LE BIEN AIME  100ml edp test
A.Banderas  BLUE SED. ELECTRIC women 100ml  test
A.Dunhill  BLACK men 100ml edt
```

Как извлечь только название, а обьем и следушее за ним - удалить?

Comment: найдите индекс "100ml" и возьмите срез до него

Comment: а что, дубликат некому поискать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rows = [
    '12 PARFUMEURS  LE BIEN AIME  100ml edp test',
    'A.Banderas  BLUE SED. ELECTRIC women 100ml  test',
    'A.Dunhill  BLACK men 100ml edt',
]
```

Найдите индекс "100ml" и возьмите срез до него:

```
for row in rows:
   volume_index = row.index('100ml')
   print(row[:volume_index])
```

выведет:

```
12 PARFUMEURS  LE BIEN AIME  
A.Banderas  BLUE SED. ELECTRIC women 
A.Dunhill  BLACK men
```

Или так:

```
new_rows = [row[:row.index('100ml')].strip() for row in rows]
```

чтоб сразу и в список, и без лишних пробелов:

```
>>> new_rows
['12 PARFUMEURS  LE BIEN AIME', 'A.Banderas  BLUE SED. ELECTRIC women', 'A.Dunhill  BLACK men']
```

---

UPD "в том и дело что women и men тоже убирать надо, но они не везде есть" решается с помощью `.replace()`:

```
new_rows = [row[:row.index('100ml')].replace('women', '').replace('man', '').strip() for row in rows]
```

`.replace()` не вызовет ошибки, даже если не найдет шаблон для замены:

```
>>> new_rows
['12 PARFUMEURS  LE BIEN AIME', 'A.Banderas  BLUE SED. ELECTRIC', 'A.Dunhill  BLACK']
```

Comment: в том и дело что women и men  тоже убирать надо, но они не везде есть

Comment: @СергейБогданов добавил решение в ответ

Comment: @ Jack_oS Да! Спасибо! Галочку поставил) Хорошего дня!

Comment: @ Jack_oS Я эти строки парсю из эксель файла. Их там тьма и вводятся построчно. А как сразу их сложить в список, чтоб потом с ним работать?

Comment: @СергейБогданов вопрос: как прочитать .xlsx файл? можно использовать [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Нет. Вопрос в том Как полученные  из файла .xlsx данные в список сложить?

Comment: @СергейБогданов как вы сейчас получаете данные из xlsx? вычитываете значения из ячеек? просто добавляйте их в словарь в этом же цикле...